# What do you call this device which plugs into the wall so you can have more electrical sockets nearby?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

I haven't found anything related to this device neither on internet nor in dictionaries

[image: device which plugs into the wall and has 3 electrical sockets where other devices can be plugged in]

It is an equipment used to make up for the problem of not having enough sockets, nearby.

Comment: English speakers almost everywhere call these things 'power strips', not just Americans. A power outlet (or 'power socket' in Britain) has just one place for connecting something electrical.

Comment: In the USA, "power strip"  Power outlet is used nearly exclusively for the plugs that are within a wall.

Comment: This question [has also been asked on English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482380/what-s-the-word-for-a-multi-outlet-extension-cord). There seems to be no general agreement on what it is called. Various different suggestions are given - one of which is "power strip".

Comment: I'd call it a "4-way" (or in this case, a "3-way"). If more clarity is required, "A three way extension".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to talk about this item. Here are a few ways I've heard it spoken about:

1. [Power strip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/power%20strip) - like the item you have pictured, it has multiple outlets on it and plugs into the wall, and usually contains a power switch.
2. [Extension cable/cord](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_cord) (according to @Canadian Yankee, an **extension lead** in the UK) - kind of similar to a power strip, but it only has one outlet and usually a longer cable, and usually doesn't have an on off switch. **This is different from the item pictured, but is still used to bring power to a place where there is none.**
3. [Outlet strip](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_strip) - just another way to say power strip.
4. [Surge protector](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surge_protector) - though this looks the same as a power strip/outlet strip, a surge protector has special circuitry to protect your devices against a power surge. Though it's a specific type of power/outlet strip, people usually use them interchangeably these days, because many people don't know the difference.

Bear in mind, I'm an American English speaker in the Pacific Northwest, so those are the terms we use out here. Other people may have other ways of saying it, but if you use one of those three properly, people will understand what you mean.

Comment: It would not be an extension cord. An extension cord is single cord to make an existing power cord longer.

Comment: Did you read how I defined it? I'm aware it's not synonymous with power strip which is why I put a separate definition. In his question, he asked at the end for the name of something you use if you don't have enough sockets nearby. You can use an extension cord to bring a socket to another location if you don't have one nearby, hence my answer Including extension cords.

Comment: I believe that the more typical UK term for #2 is **extension lead**.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I added to answer and gave credit.

Comment: An extension cord is generally a single electric cord with a plug at one end and a socket at the other. Also, it may have multiple sockets according to Wikipedia, but generally does not. I would not say that an extension cord is "similar" to a power strip. One is for making cords longer and the other is for plugging in various things on one strip. Their functions are different. They may be used in tandem with each other, yes.

Comment: I agree with you on what an extension cord is! There is no question that it usually refers to a long cord with one plug. I included all of those things specifically in my definition. To quote: kind of **similar** to a power strip, but it only **has one outlet** and usually a **longer cable**, and usually **doesn't have an on off switch.**. It was appropriate to include in the answer because OP asked for the name of a device that adds sockets if you have none nearby. If you were outside and needed a socket, you could use an extension cord. Just my thought.

Comment: Just to bring you satisfaction though, I edited in an extra note to that part of my answer.

Comment: In my experience  an "extension cord" is normally a relatively long cord with a plug at one end (often 3 to 12 feet, but sometimes as long as 100 or 150 feet for outdoor use). But for indoor use it almost always has three sockets, often in a cubical formation.  But I agree that I would not use the term for the pictured item

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the image you attached would indeed be called a "power strip".

A "power outlet" would be a socket for power plugs that is attached to the wall or some similar surface (floor, etc).

Alternatively, you may call *one* of the sockets in the power strip a "power outlet", as in "Are there any [power] outlets left in the power strip that are still empty? I need to plug in my charger."

Answer (score 2):

What you have in the picture is a **power strip** or a **power bar**.

[See this Wikipedia entry for more information.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_strip)

A **power outlet**, **power point**, **outlet**, **receptacle**, or **socket** is ​a device in a wall that you put a plug into in order to connect electrical equipment to the power supply of a building. (Oxford Dictionary). It can also refer to any of the individual sockets on a power strip.